Time evolution of state in first and second quantization
I was trying to work out the time evolution of a single particle state in second quantization and got something apparently contradicting with the first quantized picture.
For a system with energy eigenvalues $\{\varepsilon_i\}$, the second quantized Hamiltonian is $\hat{H}=\sum_i \varepsilon_i \hat{c}^\dagger_i \hat{c}_i$. In Heisenberg picture the creation operator at time $t$ is obtained by $\frac{d}{dt}\hat{c}^\dagger_i = \frac{1}{i\hbar}[\hat{c}^\dagger_i, \hat{H}]$ which gives $\hat{c}^\dagger_i(t) = e^{i\varepsilon_it/\hbar}\hat{c}^\dagger_i(0)$.
If we now consider the time evolution of an eigenstate $|j\rangle$, at $t=0$ we have $|\psi(t=0)\rangle=\hat{c}_j^\dagger(0)|vac\rangle=|j\rangle$ where $|vac\rangle$ is the vacuum state. At time $t$ we have $|\psi(t)\rangle = \hat{c}_j^\dagger(t)|vac\rangle=e^{i\varepsilon_jt/\hbar}\hat{c}^\dagger_j(0)|vac\rangle=e^{i\varepsilon_jt/\hbar}|\psi(0)\rangle = e^{i\varepsilon_jt/\hbar}|j\rangle$.
However, if we simply consider the time evolution operator in first quantization, $U(t)=\exp{(-iHt/\hbar)}$, then we expect an eigenstate $|j\rangle$ has time evolution $|\psi(t)\rangle=e^{-i\varepsilon_jt/\hbar}|j\rangle$.
The two results are off by a minus sign in front of the $i$ in the exponential. I don't think the two method should give a different answer but where is the problem in my calculation?


For a system with energy eigenvalues $\{\varepsilon_i\}$, the second quantized Hamiltonian is $\hat{H}=\sum_i \varepsilon_i \hat{c}^\dagger_i \hat{c}_i$. In Heisenberg picture the creation operator at time $t$ is obtained by $\frac{d}{dt}\hat{c}^\dagger_i = \frac{1}{i\hbar}[\hat{c}^\dagger_i, \hat{H}]$...

This is fine.

If we now consider the time evolution of an eigenstate $|j\rangle$, at $t=0$ we have $|\psi(t=0)\rangle=\hat{c}_j^\dagger(0)|vac\rangle=|j\rangle$ where $|vac\rangle$ is the vacuum state.

Ok. This definition for a $t=0$ state is fine.

At time $t$ we have $|\psi(t)\rangle = \hat{c}_j^\dagger(t)|vac\rangle=\ldots$.

No. This is wrong. At time t you have:
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{-iHt}|\psi(0)\rangle\;.
$$
You don't just get to redefine time evolution however you would like. Remember, the purpose of the definition
$$
\mathcal{O}(t) = e^{iHt}\mathcal{O}(0)e^{-iHt}
$$
is to preserve expectation values between the Heisenberg and Schrodinger pictures, such that
$$
\langle \psi(0)|\mathcal{O}(t)|\psi (0)\rangle 
= 
\langle \psi(t)|\mathcal{O}(0)|\psi (t)\rangle\;
$$

However, if we simply consider the time evolution operator in first quantization, $U(t)=\exp{(-iHt/\hbar)}$,

This the time evolution operator that acts on the state regardless of if it is "first quantization" or "second quantization."

The two results are off by a minus sign in front of the $i$ in the exponential. I don't think the two method should give a different answer but where is the problem in my calculation?

The problem is the first calculation you present is wrong.
